# @JoinFormula in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting started with Hibernate and I have such problem I do not understand such line in code I am analysing:

```
@JoinFormula( "REGEXP_REPLACE(phoneNumber, '\\+(\\d+)-.*', '\\1')::int" )
```

The source I am using is: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables

I don't know where is the dependency between country Id and phoneNumber.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a little bit after that snippet, you'd find

> The `country` association in the `User` entity is mapped by the country
>   identifier provided by the `phoneNumber` property.

And

> Therefore, the `@JoinFormula` annotation is used to define a **custom join**
>   association between the parent-child association.

---

Basically, the `JOIN` between `User` and `Country` is made by that **calculated value**.

For example, a `User` with a number

```
+40-123-4567
```

is `JOIN`ed with a `Country` that had an ID of

```
40
```

because the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function is able to extrapolate that `40` from the number.

`::int` is a type cast.

Comment: So REGEXP_REPLACE does return value based on replace_string argument?It misleads because I understand replace_string is changing text(in first argument)

Comment: @graluc REGEXP_REPLACE  will take as input the phoneNumber value, and output another value, manipulated using the inputted regex.

Comment: @graluc in this case it will split the string by " - " and take only the first occurence, considering only numbers.

Comment: @graluc hi! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your doubts. In case let me know if you need other clatifications